# How do I make a fullscreen window minimize when I hit the windows key?

Tags: windows, winapi

I've always noticed that in windows games, when you hit the windows key, the screen changes its resolution back to normal, the game window minimizes, and the start menu pops up. When I do it, the start menu just pops up over my window. How do I do it right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a [Low-Level Keyboard Hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) to catch the initial Windows key KeyDown event and then process a [WM_SIZE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632646%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) message to minimize the window before continuing to process the Windows key keypress?